# Group by and aggregate tuples in Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tuples, aggregate

I'm working with Spark SQL and Java. I have a dataset with duplicate clients grouped by ENTITY and DOCUMENT_ID. I added a rownumber column to know how many clients are there (and I have to compare) for each group:

```
.withColumn( "ROWNUMBER", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("ENTITY", "ENTITY_DOC").orderBy("ID")))
```

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+
|ROWNUMBER|  ENTITY  |      ENTITY_DOC |    ID    |  BLOCK    |  TYPE_DOC |COD_BEST|COD_CRITERIO|
+---------+----------+-----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+
|        1|       182|000004693R       |   5254578|          3|         01|       0|           0|
|        2|       182|000004693R       |  99841470|          0|         01|       0|           0|
|        3|       182|000004693R       |  45866239|          3|         01|       0|           0|
|        1|       182|000081638B       |  99804050|          0|         01|       0|           0|
|        2|       182|000081638B       |  99803968|          0|         01|       0|           0|
|        3|       182|000081638B       |  99803958|          0|         01|       0|           0|
|        4|       182|000081638B       |  99804054|          0|         01|       0|           0|
|        5|       182|000081638B       |  99787706|          1|         01|       0|           0|
|        6|       182|000081638B       |  99803930|          0|         01|       0|           0|
|        1|       182|000107084L       |  99819126|          0|         01|       0|           0|
|        2|       182|000107084L       |  99818446|          0|         01|       0|           0|
+---------+----------+-----------------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+
```

Now I have to compare pairs of rows in order to decide which is the best.

```
First compare rownumber1 vs rownumber2 (if rownumber2 is the best) then
compare rownumber2 vs rownumber3 (if rownumber3 is the best)
then compare rownumber3 vs rownumber4 ... etc
```

It is decided which is the best based on certain business criteria like:

```
//criteria 1
BLOCK = 1 VS BLOCK 1
   //go to the next criteria
//criteria 2
BLOCK = 2 VS BLOCK 1
   //the best is BLOCK 2

//criteria3
TYPE_DOC = 1 VS TYPE_DOC = 1
 //go to the next criteria

//criteria4
 TYPE_DOC = 1 VS TYPE_DOC = 2
  //the best is TYPE_DOC 1

(not is a logical example but to get an idea)
```

In the end I have to know which is the best row of each group and by what criteria it has been selected, but I don't know how to iterate each group to compare the fields of its rows.

Would it be very difficult to do?

Comment: I read your answer @blackbishop, I think it's a very good idea and very useful (I didnt know how go through a dataset) but it's a problem when you group many tuples, the columns can become almost infinite and the performance of the process drops a lot. So I have thought, before forming tuples, to evaluate the rows and calculate "the best" to have it as a reference and then form the tuples with "the best row" and the other duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can first assign `row_number` for each duplicate then create a map from the columns and add the row number as suffix for each key. Finally group by `ENTITY`, `DOCUMENT_ID` and collect the list of maps, concatenate them and pivot after exploding the map.

Note that here I'm mainly using SQL expressions as I'm not very familiar with Spark Java API but the logic is the same if you want to convert them to use API functions.

```java
Dataset < Row > tuples = duplicates.withColumn(
    "rn",
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("ENTITY", "DOCUMENT_ID").orderBy("ID"))
).withColumn(
    "dupes",
    expr("map(concat('COUNTRY_', rn), COUNTRY, concat('ID_', rn), ID, concat('CUSTOMER_NAME_', rn), CUSTOMER_NAME)")
).groupBy("ENTITY", "DOCUMENT_ID").agg(
    collect_list("dupes").alias("dupes")
).selectExpr(
    "ENTITY",
    "DOCUMENT_ID",
    "explode(aggregate(dupes, cast(map() as map<string,string>), (acc, x) -> map_concat(acc, x)))"
).groupBy(
    "ENTITY", "DOCUMENT_ID"
).pivot("key").agg(first("value"));


tuples.show();

//+------+-----------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+
//|ENTITY|DOCUMENT_ID|COUNTRY_1|COUNTRY_2|CUSTOMER_NAME_1|CUSTOMER_NAME_2|    ID_1|    ID_2|
//+------+-----------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+
//|    11|  A06804173|        9|        9|     Elton John|     Elton John|12341000|13701921|
//+------+-----------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+--------+--------+
```

---

Another way would be to group by your key columns and collect list of structs then using the max size of the resulting arrays, access the elements and create multiples columns. Something like this:

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

Dataset<Row> tuples = duplicates.groupBy("ENTITY", "DOCUMENT_ID").agg(
    collect_list(expr("struct(COUNTRY, ID, CUSTOMER_NAME)")).alias("dupes")
);

int maxSize = tuples.select(max(size(col("dupes")))).first().getInt(0);

Column[] dupes = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, maxSize - 1)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Column[]{
                col("dupes").getItem(i).getField("COUNTRY").alias("COUNTRY_" + i),
                col("dupes").getItem(i).getField("ID").alias("ID_" + i),
                col("dupes").getItem(i).getField("CUSTOMER_NAME").alias("CUSTOMER_NAME_" + i),
        }).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(Column[]::new);

tuples.select(
    Stream.of(new Column[]{col("ENTITY"), col("DOCUMENT_ID")}, dupes)
            .flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(Column[]::new)
).show();
```